# Is there any TugStatus (since there is StackStatus...)

Tags: tugboat

The TeX Users Group website seems to be down just now: http://tug.org/

Is there any way to know what is going on? Maybe something similar to StackStatus (either the website or the twitter account) for the StackExchange network? Do TUG have any other official resource, like on social networks, that could be used by the TUG headquarters to communicate the website status?

Comment: I think this is a relevant question on the site, because tug.org is an important resource for the users. However, I couldn't find a suitable tag for it. Any ideas?

Comment: I think it's off topic really, and for the current issue, tug.org (now it's back) says Intermittent tug.org outage Nov. 14-15, due to infrastructure work. Exact hours of (un)availability cannot be known in advance; expect fluctuations.

Comment: The University where TUG.org is hosted has service windows like this every 3 months. Sometimes Web stuff is affected, other times they are not.

Comment: Hmm, actually this one wasn't planned, they have an acute power failure which is not a part of the service window, and they are working on it. http://driftstatus.au.dk/Info/Details/1582 (in Danish)